# norm one approximate identities in separable C* algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

I'm trying to prove Corollary 1.4.9 in K. Davidson's book (Exercise 1.5):

If A is a separable C* algebra, then there is an increasing sequence
$E_i, i=1,...,\infty$ of positive norm-one elements which form an approximate
identity for A.

The hint suggests to choose $E_n$ successively so that 
$||E_n A_k - A_k|| < \frac{1}{n}$ for all $k$ from $1$ to $n$.

It is clear from how approximate identities are constructed in this
book that this can be done with $||E_i||<1$.  Why can the $E_i$ be 
chosen to be increasing and norm = 1?

Comment: What is $A_k$? (I also feel this question would be more appropriate for http://math.stackexchange.com; either the hint is mistaken, or the exercise is not "research level", or both.)

Comment: $(A_k)$ is a dense sequence in the C*-algebra.